# lvmraid: How are the disks raided?

Tags: raid, lvm

When using traditional raid solutions, each raid device is a mirror of each other. But `lvs -a -o +devices` shows a lv_mlog created on just one specific device. Doesn't this mean if anything were to happen to that drive, nothing is recoverable?

Comment: raid 1 is mirrored, so i was expecting everything, including the meta logs to be mirrored. But it isn't so. In addition lvm can raid across extents and not just disks. though why this is happens should only be as a temporary measure to start shifting data into similar sized hardware disks. 

zfs itself, and only the disk replication, is just an extension of the raid classifications. It doesn't mean you'll get zero data loss, just a probabilistically low chance.

Comment: Unless it's hardware raid, everything is software, so it isn't handled by bios. The only plus about zfs is the deduplication, snapshots and send/receive over the network data blocks.